# Change color of imagebutton on clicking it in Recyclerview

Tags: android, onclick, android-recyclerview, imagebutton

I have implemented recyclerview with an image and image-Button below it. I have set a toast when i click on the image button and i also want to change the color of the imagebutton when i click it color changes of all the items that are in that position after view has gone out of visible area i.e if i clicked at 2nd image-button then all the visible 2nd image-buttons come as colored

how can i solve this??

this is my code:

```
package com.example.tatson.bila;       

public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder>  {


    private String imageUrl;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context context;
    String Load;
    static int count = 0;
    public static final String uu = "uu";
    String number;
    String  user1;
    public static final String UserNum = "UserNum";
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;

    private String[] pos;
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private boolean loading;
    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;
    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    String url,imgoffset;
    //testing from a real server:
    private static final String LIKE_URL = "my php";

    //ids
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    List<SuperHeroes> superHeroes1;
    //List of superHeroes

    List<SuperHeroes> superHeroes;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;


    public CardAdapter() {
    }

    public CardAdapter(List<SuperHeroes> superHeroes, Context context) {
        super();
        //Getting all the superheroes
        this.superHeroes = superHeroes;
        superHeroes1= superHeroes;
        this.context = context;
        sharedPref  =context.getSharedPreferences(UserNum, 0);
        number =  sharedPref.getString(uu, "");    
    }    

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.superheroes_list, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;    
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        SuperHeroes superHero = superHeroes.get(position);
       Log.d("position", String.valueOf(position));
        Log.d("url", superHero.getImageUrl());
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(superHero.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

        holder.imageView.setImageUrl(superHero.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
        holder.textViewName.setText(superHero.getName());
        holder.textViewRank.setText(String.valueOf(superHero.getRank()));

        // holder.textViewPowers.setText(powers);
        holder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ImageButton like =(ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.button_like);
                like.setImageResource(R.drawable.plike);

                        SuperHeroes s = superHeroes.get(position);

                        Load = s.getImageUrl();
                        Log.d("test", Load);    

                        new LikeIt().execute();    
            }
        });    
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return superHeroes.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public NetworkImageView imageView;

        public TextView textViewName;
        public TextView textViewRank;
        public TextView textViewRealName;
        public TextView textViewCreatedBy;
        public TextView textViewFirstAppearance;
        public TextView textViewPowers;
       public ImageButton like;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
            textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            textViewRank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRank);
            // textViewRealName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRealName);
            // textViewCreatedBy= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCreatedBy);
            // textViewFirstAppearance= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFirstAppearance);
            // textViewPowers= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPowers);
            like = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_like);

        }    
    }

     class LikeIt extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag

             int success;

            String Imgurl = Load;
            Log.d("request!", number);

          //  try {
                // Building Parameters
                HashMap<String, String> Params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Params.put("Imgurl", Imgurl);
           Params.put("user", number);


                Log.d("request!", "starting");    

                String encodedStr = getEncodedData(Params);

                //Will be used if we want to read some data from server
                BufferedReader reader = null;

                //Connection Handling
                try {
                    //Converting address String to URL
                    URL url = new URL(LIKE_URL);
                    //Opening the connection (Not setting or using CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    //Post Method
                    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    //To enable inputting values using POST method
                    //(Basically, after this we can write the dataToSend to the body of POST method)
                    con.setDoOutput(true);
                    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
                    //Writing dataToSend to outputstreamwriter
                    writer.write(encodedStr);
                    //Sending the data to the server - This much is enough to send data to server
                    //But to read the response of the server, you will have to implement the procedure below
                    writer.flush();

                    //Data Read Procedure - Basically reading the data comming line by line
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                    String line;
                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { //Read till there is something available
                        sb.append(line + "\n");     //Reading and saving line by line - not all at once
                    }
                    line = sb.toString();           //Saving complete data received in string, you can do it differently

                    //Just check to the values received in Logcat
                    Log.i("custom_check","The values :");
                    Log.i("custom_check", line);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if(reader != null) {
                        try {
                            reader.close();     //Closing the
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                //Same return null, but if you want to return the read string (stored in line)
                //then change the parameters of AsyncTask and return that type, by converting
                //the string - to say JSON or user in your case
                return null;
            }

        }
    private String getEncodedData(Map<String,String> data) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(String key : data.keySet()) {
            String value = null;
            try {
                value = URLEncoder.encode(data.get(key), "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(sb.length()>0)
                sb.append("&");

            sb.append(key + "=" + value);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         **/
        protected void onPostExecute() {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

old question and unanswered so for you or future or current searchers i am posting answer.

Instead of defining the click listener inside *onBindViewHolder* do it simply inside your class *ViewHolder* like i posted below, it will avoid calling the clicks of item inside RecyclerView and the whole row at a time, same can also be done with your approach but that's expensive, read [**THIS**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33845846/2736849) why defining click events inside *onBindViewHolder* is not good practise.

Now coming towards answer part how to change color of imageButton on click and display a toast.

**RecyclerAdapter Class:**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ItemsViewHolder>{

private static List<MapperClass> wordsList;
// some other variables to use

public RecyclerAdapter(Context con, List<MapperClass> wordsList){
    RecyclerAdapter.wordsList=wordsList;
    RecyclerAdapter.context=con;
}

public static class ItemsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView txtViewWord,txtViewPOS;
    ImageButton imgButtonFavourite;
    boolean starred = false; //for checking that row is starred(favourite-d) or not      
                       // & to avoid resetting of imageButton on scroll of recyclerView. 


    public ItemsViewHolder(View itemView){ //here you should define click events.
        super(itemView);

        txtViewWord = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtView_Word);
        txtViewPOS = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtView_PartOfSpeech);
        imgButtonFavourite = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgButton_Favourite);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgButtonFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(starred){ 
                    Drawable starEmpty = view.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favourite);
                    starEmpty.setBounds(0,0,24,24);
                    imgButtonFavourite.setBackground(starEmpty);
                }else{ //here i am setting another pic when user marks word favourite i.e.
                     // filled star , you can change color of imageButton here instead of
                     // changing icon, u can simply getColor from getResource
                     // and pass it desired color                  
                    Drawable startFilled = view.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favourite_filled);
                    startFilled.setBounds(0,0,24,24);
                    imgButtonFavourite.setBackground(startFilled);

        //here instead of normal toast, i used Snackbar :D (Toast on Steroids) **requires design support library**  
       //when you will click imageButton a snackBar will pop out
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Icon changed of imageButton", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      // here you have toast as well, use any one 
      //Toast.makeText(view, "Icon changed of imageButton", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }                   
                starred = !starred;             
            }   
        });
    }
```

This way you can change the icon or change color of imageButton upon clickcing it and also show a message.

This might be helpful for some.