# Handle click events in Adapter/ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-viewholder, android-popupwindow

**Currently**:
I'm implementing click events in my `Adapter` inside of `onBindViewHolder`, but I have noticed that the adapter positions get messed up when doing this. I done some research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33845951/8199772), where he state:

> As for why it is better in the ViewHolder instead of in onBindViewHolder(), that is because onBindViewHolder() is called for each and every item and setting the click listener is an unnecessary option to repeat when you can call it once in your ViewHolder constructor.

and the example he refer to looks like this:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnItemClickListener {
   public MyViewHolder(View view) {
      super(view);

      view.setOnClickListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void OnClick(View view) {
      // Get the item clicked
      // For this example, I'm assuming your data source is of type `List<MyObject>`
      MyObject myObject = mDataSource.get(getAdapterPosition());
      // Then you can do any actions on it, for example - 
      myObject.setChecked();
   }
}
```

This makes sense to me, but my issue is that I have a `ImageButton` inside my `ViewHolder` and his example is only showing how to handle click events for the `ViewHolder` itself. Please first have a look at how my adapter currently looks like:

```
public class MyAdapter extends Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArrayList;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    View myLayoutView;
    ArrayList<PathModel> swingThumbPathList;
    ArrayList<PathModel> swingVideoPathList = new ArrayList();

    class ViewHolder extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        CircularImageView image;
        ImageButton viewholderOtions;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        this.myLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(this.myLayoutView);
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder myHolder, final int position) {
        final ViewHolder holder = myHolder;
        holder.viewholderOtions = (ImageButton) myLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.viewholderOptions);
        holder.name = (TextView) this.myLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.image = (CircularImageView) this.myLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.name.setText(Model.getPath());
        holder.image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(Model.getPath()));

        holder.viewholderOtions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), "Options was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                showPopupMenu(holder.viewholderOtions, position);

            }
        });

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String uri = holder.name.getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), uri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        });

    }

    private void showPopupMenu(final View view, final int position) {
        // inflate menu
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), view);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.delete:
                        //The correct position is being toasted
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), position + "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        return true;
                    case R.id.rename:
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Rename", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        return true;

                    default:

                        return true;
                }
            }

        });

        popup.show();
    }
```

**My Question**

How can I handle click events of the `ViewHolder` itself and the `ImageButton` inside of the `ViewHolder`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a laugh looking back at this question, so answering my own question almost 2 years later.

Using the same logic provided in the question, this is how you will go about setting click event to the view itself, as well as the elements inside the view, inside viewholder instead of `onBindViewHolder`

```
public class MyAdapter extends Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArrayList;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    View myLayoutView;
    ArrayList<PathModel> swingThumbPathList;
    ArrayList<PathModel> swingVideoPathList = new ArrayList();

    class ViewHolder extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        CircularImageView image;
        ImageButton viewholderOtions;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            viewholderOtions = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewholderOptions);
            videoName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.FilePath);
            videoThumb = itemView.findViewById(R.id.VideoThumbnail);
            //set OnClickListener's for the views we want click events for 
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            viewholderOtions.setOnClickListener(this);
            videoThumb.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //get the tag that we have set in onBindViewHolder
            int position = (int) v.getTag();
            if (v == viewholderOtions) {
                //viewholderOtions was selected, we can use the position above to see what item, as shown below:
                Log.e("viewholderOtions at position =", String.valueOf(position);
            }
            if (v == itemView){
                //itemView was selected, we can use the position above to see what item, as shown below:
                Log.e("itemView at position =", String.valueOf(position);
            }
            if (v == videoThumbvideoThumb){
                //itemView was selected, we can use the position above to see what item, as shown below:
                Log.e("videoThumbvideoThumb at position =", String.valueOf(position);
            }
        }


    }

    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        this.myLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(this.myLayoutView);
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder myHolder, final int position) {
        //set a tag so we can retrieve the position via the tag
        myHolder.viewholderOtions.setTag(position);

        //Set text to holder.name
        holder.name.setText(Model.getPath());
        //a better option to below is to use a library like picasso to handle the image loading
        holder.image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(Model.getPath()));       

    }

}
```

But to be honest, I still set the click events inside `onBindViewHolder`, then I just set the following to my `RecyclerView` inside my `Activity` - `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);`. By doing the the positions will not get messed up, as stated in my question.

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewHolder constructor do something like this

```
class ViewHolder extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    CircularImageView image;
    ImageButton viewholderOtions;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        // initialize your view here and set click listener 
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
           // do your stuffs

          }
        });
    }
    public void setText(String text){
      // do your thing
    }
}
```

Now in your `onBindViewHolder`

```
   @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setText("The text you want to pass to view holder");
}
```

And also I don't think its good idea to use global `myLayoutView`. It will mess up with your view. Instead  use `viewHolder.itemview`

Comment: thank you for answering, how will I then get text from my holder inside `onBindViewHolder ` to `ViewHolder(View itemView)`?

Comment: as well as the position of the selected `ViewHolder`

Comment: i didn't get what you trying to say. Did you mean you want to pass text to your `viewHolder` from `onBindViewhHolder`? If yes then create a method in your `ViewHolder` something like `setText(String text)` and call it from `onBindViewHolder` like this `viewHolder.setText("your text")`. Same goes for the position.

Comment: Can you please update your answer and show me what you mean? I only need this then your answer is the accepted answer