# Cannot access var object of inner class in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to write a RecyclerView adapter class in Kotlin for android. I am trying to use the traditional way of creating a custom viewer class, for custom objects, and use a click listener in that. While I am able to do rest of the things like access the variables of inner class and show the RecyclerView, what I have not been able to do is add click listener to the var objects of inner class.

ie something like

```
 var convertView : View? = itemView

convertView.setOnClickListener(this)
```

Following is my complete code of adapter class

```
public open class TestAdapter(val items: MutableList<Any>, val context: Activity) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TestAdapter.CustomViewHolder>() {

public var mItem: MutableList<Any> = items
public var mActivity: Activity = context
protected var clickListener: ExampleInterface? = null
public interface ExampleInterface {

    fun click(pos: Int) {

    }
}


open public fun setListener(mInterFaceListener: ExampleInterface) {
    clickListener = mInterFaceListener
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): CustomViewHolder {
    var parentLayout: View = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity).inflate(R.layout.custom_view, p0, false)
    return CustomViewHolder(parentLayout)

    //  return CustomViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(mActivity).inflate(R.layout.custom_view, p0, false))
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return mItem.size
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: CustomViewHolder, p1: Int) {

    p0.dataView.text = mItem.get(p1).toString()

}

inner class CustomViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
    var convertView: View? = itemView
    var dataView: TextView = convertView!!.findViewById(R.id.data)

    var mposition = adapterPosition

    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {

        if (clickListener != null) {
            clickListener!!.click(mposition)
        }
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

}
```

}

So if you see these two lines in CustomView class

```
var convertView: View? = itemView
    var dataView: TextView = convertView!!.findViewById(R.id.data)
```

I cannot access these variables "convertView" and "dataView" so that I can set clicklistener to them. So how to achieve it ?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `RecyclerView` adapters, You could place the `OnClickListeners` in `onCreateViewHolder` in order to prevent them from being set each time `onBindViewHolder` is called (as `onBindViewHolder` is called multiple times when `RecyclerView` is scrolled). Use `parentLayout` in your `onCreateViewHolder` to access your views and set `onClickListener` to them. to determine current position in `onCreateViewHolder` you can do as below :

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): CustomViewHolder {
    val parentLayout: View = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity).inflate(R.layout.custom_view, p0, false)
    
    val customViewHolder = CustomViewHolder(parentLayout)
    parentLayout.myExampleTextView.setOnClickListener {
        // Place onClick logic here.

        // If you need position, do as bellow :
        val adapterPosition = customViewHolder.adapterPosition
        if(adapterPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            // Place your position dependent logic here
        }
    }
    
    return customViewHolder
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I updated the code snippet above and added the `RecyclerView.NO_POSITION` (which is equal to -1) check. The reason for the position being returned as -1 is explained below.

> From android docs:
>
> The other set of position related methods are in the form of
> *AdapterPosition*. (e.g. getAdapterPosition(), findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(int)) You should use these methods
> when you need to work with up-to-date adapter positions even if they
> may not have been reflected to layout yet. For example, if you want to
> access the item in the adapter on a ViewHolder click, you should use
> getAdapterPosition(). Beware that these methods may not be able to
> calculate adapter positions if notifyDataSetChanged() has been called
> and new layout has not yet been calculated. For this reasons, you
> should carefully handle NO_POSITION or null results from these
> methods.

Comment: Hey can you please let me know where to write this code for postion 
var adapterPosition = viewHolder.adapterPosition
Coz in onCreateViewHolder I am getting it as -1

Comment: Should this be in bindViewHolder and not in onCreateViewHolder ??

Comment: @Pritish I updated the answer, -1 being returned is explained and handled with an if statement, it should be handled to avoid any problem. 
As why to place `onClickListener` in `onCreateViewHolder`, take a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33845918/8551764

Comment: It's better to put that code into the CustomViewHolder's constructor, actually.

Answer (score 1):

I referred to this site

> https://www.raywenderlich.com/367-android-recyclerview-tutorial-with-kotlin

Here I go to know my mistake , I need to use init in the class, there I am able to access it and initialize on click listener. Got it working

```
   init {
            convertView?.setOnClickListener(this)
        }
```

Though the above answer could be acceptable as well, as I am new to Kotlin I cannot say which one is the better option, but my requirement is satisfied with the above mentioned site.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can access them in the `onBindViewHolder` using the `p0` this way `p0.dataView` so there you can set listeners successfully

Comment: Yes but is it the proper way to do it ?? As bind holder is exclusively meant for setting data and it will keep on setting listener on every bind. Isn't it the reason we used to do that in custom view class traditionally in Java.

Comment: N idea, I used it this way and it always works, never faced any problems @Pritish

Comment: So you write it separately for every variable like 
 p0.dataView.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {  })
 p0.dataView1.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {  })

Comment: no I do not ,it generates the listener to all (dataView)s, you may use the p1 to get the position of each one of the Views and customize adding the listeners @Pritish