# Did i need to share an item from onBindViewHolder() to ViewHolder?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-listview, android-viewholder

I'm a junior in android developpement and i'm looking for the best implementation of my Viewholder / onBindViewHolder.

Here is what android studio give us when he build a fragment (list) :

```
public class MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    //some code

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        holder.mIdView.setText(mValues.get(position).id);
        holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).content);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public final TextView mIdView;
        public final TextView mContentView;
        public DummyItem mItem;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_number);
            mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
        }

        //some code
    }

}
```

Why the item is send to the ViewHolder ? And why he isn't used in the onBindViewHolder for updating TextViews ?
Like this :

```
public class MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    //some code

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        holder.mIdView.setText(holder.mItem.id);
        holder.mContentView.setText(holder.mItem.content);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public final TextView mIdView;
        public final TextView mContentView;
        public DummyItem mItem;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_number);
            mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
        }

        //some code
    }

}
```

And finnaly what i was doing for the moment.
Not sending the item to the ViewHolder :

```
public class MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    //some code

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        DummyItem mItem = mValues.get(position);
        holder.mIdView.setText(mItem.id);
        holder.mContentView.setText(mItem.content);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public final TextView mIdView;
        public final TextView mContentView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_number);
            mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
        }

        //some code
    }

}
```

What's the best way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you're talking about but from what I understand, Your view holder can contain all the the UI and methods and logics, however I prefer the third method as it is more clear than the rest 2.

That being said please Look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33845951/11774167) AdaMc331 explains how do these methods work and how should you use them.

Comment: Thank's for the help ! Perfectly what i was expecting and more.