# Adding data from parent recyclerview adapter and removing data from child recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a nested recyclerview. Parent recyclerview adapter can add a data to child by a button, then child recyclerview adapter can remove a data in child by a button. The preview is like below.

[image: The preview]

Adding data seems fine, but when removing data i got index out of bound. I have called `notifyDataSetChanged()` in add or remove function.

My parent adapter code :

```
class FormPlanParentAdapter :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<FormPlanParentAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private val data: MutableList<MutableList<ItemPlan>> = mutableListOf()

    private val viewPool = RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool()

    fun setData(newData: List<MutableList<ItemPlan>>) {
        data.clear()
        data.addAll(newData)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun getData(): String = Gson().toJson(data)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_plan_parent, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = data.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(
        holder: ViewHolder,
        position: Int
    ) {
        val listPlans = data[position]
        val childLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(
            holder.recyclerView.context,
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
            false
        )

        val childAdapter = FormPlanChildAdapter(listPlans, object : PlanParentCallback {
            override fun deletePlan(position: Int) {
                listPlans.removeAt(position)
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        })

        holder.recyclerView.apply {
            layoutManager = childLayoutManager
            adapter = childAdapter
            setRecycledViewPool(viewPool)
        }

        holder.textView.text = "Hari ke ${position + 1}"

        holder.imageButton.setOnClickListener {
            listPlans.add(ItemPlan())
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = itemView.rv_plan_child
        val textView: TextView = itemView.tv_days_of
        val imageButton: ImageButton = itemView.ib_add
    }

    interface PlanParentCallback {
        fun deletePlan(position: Int)
    }

}
```

My child adapter code :

```
class FormPlanChildAdapter(
    private val listPlans: List<ItemPlan>,
    private val callback: FormPlanParentAdapter.PlanParentCallback
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<FormPlanChildAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_plan_child, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = listPlans.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(
        holder: ViewHolder,
        position: Int
    ) {
        val itemPlan = listPlans[position]
        holder.etPlan.setText(itemPlan.plan)
        holder.etPlan.doAfterTextChanged {
            listPlans[position].plan = it.toString()
        }

        if (position == 0) {
            holder.ibDelete.invisible()
        } else {
            holder.ibDelete.visible()
        }

        holder.ibDelete.setOnClickListener {
            if (listPlans.size > 1) {
                callback.deletePlan(position)
            }
        }
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val etPlan: EditText = itemView.et_plan
        val ibDelete: ImageButton = itemView.ib_delete
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Your code is working just fine on my side!

Comment: Have you tried with more than 1 parent and 1 child? @Sarah Khan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason:**
The old `TextWatcher`s and adapter position mess up when the dataset changed.

`notifyDatasetChanged` triggers `onBindViewHolder`, and then `EditText`'s `TextWatcher` is being notified because of this line
`holder.etPlan.setText(itemPlan.plan)`

Since `etPlan` has already an active `TextWatcher` from previous binding, it tries to notify it with the old position of the adapter.

**Quick answer:**

Keep the `TextWatcher` in your `ViewHolder`, remove it from `EditText` on `onBindViewHolder`, and set it to the `EditText` again after setting the `EditText`'s value.

So, update your child adapter's onBindViewHolder as

```kotlin
    override fun onBindViewHolder(
            holder: ViewHolder,
            position: Int
    ) {
        val itemPlan = listPlans[position]
        holder.etPlan.removeTextChangedListener(holder.textWatcher)
        holder.etPlan.setText(itemPlan.plan)
        holder.textWatcher = holder.etPlan.doAfterTextChanged {
            listPlans[position].plan = it.toString()
        }

       ...
    }
```

and also update it's ViewHolder like:

```kotlin
    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val etPlan: EditText = itemView.et_plan
        val ibDelete: ImageButton = itemView.ib_delete
        var textWatcher: TextWatcher? = null
    }
```

---

**But**, it's not recommended setting listeners on `onBindViewHolder` due to performance concerns. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31860393/6470506) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33845846/why-is-adding-an-onclicklistener-inside-onbindviewholder-of-a-recyclerview-adapt).

Here is another workaround:

Move all the `TextWatcher` things to `Adapter` via a listener, and prevent notifying the `TextWatcher` if it's not necessary.

```kotlin
interface TextChangeListener {
    fun onTextChange(text: String, position: Int)
}

class FormPlanChildAdapter(...) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<FormPlanChildAdapter.ViewHolder>(), TextChangeListener {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(
        holder: ViewHolder,
        position: Int
    ) {
        val itemPlan = listPlans[position]
        holder.setPlan(itemPlan.plan)
        
        ...
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(text: String, position: Int) {
        listPlans[position].plan = text
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View, textChangeListener: TextChangeListener) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private var disableTextChangeListener = false
        private val etPlan: EditText = itemView.et_plan
        val ibDelete: ImageButton = itemView.ib_delete

        init {
            etPlan.doAfterTextChanged {
                if (!disableTextChangeListener) {
                    textChangeListener.onTextChanged(it.toString(), adapterPosition)
                }
            }
        }

        fun setPlan(plan: String, notifyTextChangeListener: Boolean = false) {
            if (notifyTextChangeListener) {
                etPlan.setText(plan)
            } else {
                disableTextChangeListener = true
                etPlan.setText(plan)
                disableTextChangeListener = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was because the listener! Also thanks for mentioning about performance concerns. But i can't implement the another answer, when i add the interface in adapter class, it errors "There's a cycle in the inheritance hierarchy for this type". Do you know why?

Comment: You may have defined `TextChangeListener` inside `FormPlanChildAdapter` which implements `TextChangeListener`. Interfaces shouldn't be placed inside of the class that is inheriting from.

Comment: I see, so where should it be placed?

Comment: Anywhere you want, except to inside of FormPlanChildAdapter. You can prefer putting it to the same file with the adapter just like the answer of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try doing

```
listPlans.removeAt(position)
notifyItemRemoved(position)
```

instead of

```
listPlans.removeAt(position)
notifyDataSetChanged()
```