# RecyclerView element OnClickListener does not react to clicks

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

The view (`test.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/files"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
```

And the item (`item.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And the code:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container, false)

    class MyViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        init {
            view.setOnClickListener {
                Log.d("path", files[adapterPosition].path)
                Log.d("pos", adapterPosition.toString())
            }
        }
    }

    val recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.files)
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
    recyclerView.adapter = object: RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
            val item = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
            return MyViewHolder(item)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text).text = files[position].name
        }

        override fun getItemCount() = files.size
    }

    return view
}
```

`files` is a local array. The items are rendered, but the log message from the `OnClickListener` does't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I named the variable for `MyViewHolder` "view", just like the first variable declared in `onCreateView`. Renaming the variable to "item" solved the problem:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.file_explorer, container, false)

    class MyViewHolder(val item: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item) {
        init {
            item.setOnClickListener {
                Log.d("path", files[adapterPosition].path)
                Log.d("pos", adapterPosition.toString())
                goto(files[adapterPosition].path)
            }
        }
    }

    val recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.files)
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
    recyclerView.adapter = object: RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
            val item = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
            return MyViewHolder(item)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.item.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text).text = files[position].name
        }

        override fun getItemCount() = files.size
    }

    return view
}
```

The mechanics of this closure resolution elude me though and I've created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66680438/unexpected-closure-resolution).

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text).text = files[position].name
    holder.view.setOnClickListener {
                Log.d("path", files[adapterPosition].path)
                Log.d("pos", adapterPosition.toString())
            }
}
```

Comment: `getAdapterPosition()` is from ViewHolder, not Adapter.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33845846/why-is-adding-an-onclicklistener-inside-onbindviewholder-of-a-recyclerview-adapt) indicates that setting the `OnClickListener` in `onBindViewHolder` is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Use FastAdapter. https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter

**Click listener:**

```
fastAdapter.onClickListener = { view, adapter, item, position ->
   // Handle click here
   false
}
```

**Click listeners for views inside your item**

```
fastAdapter.addEventHook(object : ClickEventHook<SimpleImageItem>() {
override fun onBind(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): View? {
    //return the views on which you want to bind this event
    return if (viewHolder is SimpleImageItem.ViewHolder) {
        viewHolder.viewWhichReactsOnClick
    } else {
    null
}
}

override fun onClick(v: View, position: Int, fastAdapter: FastAdapter<SimpleImageItem>, item: SimpleImageItem) {
    //react on the click event
}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine, although I see the problem may be in the top & bottom margins you add to the item, clicking on these areas won't be detected by the `clickListener` as they are not a part of the root view, and the clicks will only be detected when you tap exactly on the `TextView`

You can solve this by using padding instead in your item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: It is also possible that some transparent view is laid over the Recyclerview and blocks the clicks. Test it that is the case by adding some elevation to the view holder root layout.

Comment: @MieszkoKoźma possible reason, but I think OP shared only `RecyclerView` in `test.xml` so nothing intersecting

Comment: Using padding instead of margins didn't change anything. In any case, clicking directly on the text should've worked, if that were the problem.